# How to reference foreign key row object properties in ASP.NET Core page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and am having some difficulty understanding how to reference foreign key data data that is being provided by a stored procedure that populates an `IEnumerable` of a model that contains the foreign keys and corresponding items for the foreign model objects.

Sorry if that isn't the exact right terminology, but I'll try to provide the pertinent script. I'm able to see the foreign key id itself, but the corresponding foreign object is showing up as null.

The model includes this foreign key reference:

```
[Required]
public string RequestingUserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("RequestingUserId")]
public virtual UserViewModel? RequestingUser { get; set; }
```

The razor page includes a table that has the following:

```
@foreach (var pendingPocItem in Model.PendingPOCRequests)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @pendingPocItem.RequestingUser.FirstName
            </td>
            <td>
                @pendingPocItem.Request_Time
            </td>
            <td>
                Approve button
            </td>
            <td>
                Reject Button
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

However, while `@pendingPocItem.Request_Time` is retrieved just fine (as is `pendingPocItem.RequestingUserId`), `pendingPocItem.RequestingUser` is null, so even though intellisense lets me specify it's properties in the razor page, I get a null reference exception.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic here, but I'm not sure what.

My razor code behind:

```
[BindProperties]
public class RecommendationsModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<T_User> _userManager;
    
    protected PendingPOCService _pendingPocService;

    public IEnumerable<PendingPOC> PendingPOCRequests { get; set; }

    public RecommendationsModel(UserManager<T_User> userManager, PendingPOCService pendingPocService)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _pendingPocService = pendingPocService;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User;
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(user);
        
        PendingPOCRequests = (IEnumerable<PendingPOC>)await _pendingPocService.GetSettingsAsync(userId);
    }
}
```

My service includes the following:

```
public PendingPOCService(T_DbContext context, UserManager<TRRWS_User> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _context = context;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<PendingPOC>> GetSettingsAsync(string id)
{
    var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
    UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(user);
    LabelerCode = "XXXX01"; //hardcoded for now

    List<SqlParameter> paramList = new()
            { 
                // Create parameters    
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@UserId", Value = UserId},
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@LCode", Value = LCode}
            };

    await _context.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();

    var result = await Task.Run(() => _context.PendingPocDbSet
            .FromSqlRaw(@"EXEC GetRequests_SP @UserId, @LCode", paramList.ToArray()).ToListAsync());

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Raw SQL with EF bypasses many useful features of EF.

You've not posted the SQL query, but you could ensure that your Stored Procedure is returning all user information as well.  You'd then need to manually coerce related data from anonymous types back into your entities, e.g.:

```
var results = await _context.PendingPocDbSet
    .FromSqlRaw(@"EXEC GetRequests_SP @UserId, @LCode", paramList.ToArray())
    .Select(r => new 
    {
        PendingPoc = r,
        User = new UserViewModel 
        {
            UserId = r.UserId,
            UserName = r.UserName,
            FirstName = r.FirstName,
            // etc.
        }
    })
    .ToListAsync();

// Then, populate your entities from the anonymous types
foreach (var result in results)
{
    result.PendingPoc.RequestingUser = result.User;
}
```

But, seeing as you're using EF, it will be much easier to just go with:

```
var results = await _context.PendingPocDbSet
    .Include(p => p.RequestingUser)
    .Where(p => p.RequestingUserId == userId && p.LCode == LCode)
    .ToListAsync();
```

EF will then automatically include the related RequestingUser and all of its properties.

Comment: p.UserId doesn't resolve, so my where clause is .Where(p => p.RequestingUserId == UserId && p.LCode == LCode), however this gives me a runtime error: SqlException: Invalid object name 'UserInfoDbSet' which seems to be happening in the service function that assigns result.

Comment: Have updated the answer to use the correct property `p.RequiestingUserId`.  The other error indicates that the query generated by EF is looking for a table named `UserInfoDbSet`.  Have you configured `UserViewModel` in EF?  Is `UserViewModel` a DbSet on your context?  Does a table exist named `UserInfoDbSet`?

Comment: No, there's no table called UserInfoDbSet. that is just the name of the UserViewModel dbset in my dbcontext: public DbSet<UserViewModel> UserInfoDbSet { get; set; }